# Print only image of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a 650px X 1000px photo on a website page. There is a button below the photo.

How can I print the photo only except the full page. I want to save it as PDF or print only the image. Not save as image.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open new window using `window.open`.
2. Write to it the `img` tag.
3. Once the image was loaded, print the document using
   `window.print()`.
4. Close the window using `window.close()`

You can do this with code like this:

> Script

```js
    function printImg(url) {
  var win = window.open('');
  win.document.write('<img src="' + url + '" onload="window.print();window.close()" />');
  win.focus();
}
```

> Index.html

```html
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCYTd.jpg" />
<button onclick="printImg('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCYTd.jpg')">Print</button>
```